# Chrome native app Install banner not appearing for specific application

Tags: android, google-chrome

We're trying to get a native app install banner to appear for our application on google chrome for android.

First, we enabled the bypass app engagement checks flag at chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks

Next, we tested on the sample application at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/app-install-banner/related-applications/index.html  and we were able to successfully see the banner.

Testing on our application, however, did not work. We created a minimal example for testing purposes.

This URL contains a manifest with the application (`com.google.samples.apps.iosched`) that is used in the native install banner demo linked above.  We are able to see the banner:  https://manifest-tester-ylumqkhvvl.now.sh/

This URL contains a manifest with our actual application bundle identifier (`com.creditsights.reader.release`):  https://manifest-tester-eatfxirsoe.now.sh/  In this case, we do NOT see the banner.

The only difference between these examples is that the bundle identifier is changed.  Also, our application is NOT installed on the device.

Here is the manifest for reference:

```
{
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/icon_512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/icon_192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "name": "CreditSights",
  "short_name": "CreditSights",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": ".",
  "prefer_related_applications": true,
  "related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "play",
      "id": "com.creditsights.reader.release"
    }
  ]
}
```